# Weird date and time formating in Wordpress %Y/%m/%d

Tags: wordpress, date

Whenever someone comments on a post at the blog i am hosting (wordpress 2.9.2) the date of the comment shows as "%Y/%m/%d kl %H:%M".

I have tried to fix this, but i cant get the blog to interpret the code and put it out as the real dates and the time.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the tag for the_time in your template file is incomplete. Should be something like this:

`<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>`

If needed, see [Template Tags/the time « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) for more on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is how MySQL handles dates, so a query string isn't getting processed correctly somewhere. If you can post some code or more detail, perhaps I/someone else can give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: I think i have managed to localize the part where it goes badly. I only have trouble with the dates in comments from people.

In the comments.php file in my theme there is a block of code wich looks like:

<div class="commentlist">
  <?php wp_list_comments(array('avatar_size'=>64, reply_text'=>'Comment this')); ?>
</div>

I assume this tells wordpress to grab all comments on this certain post and list them. The code that is produced by this on a single comment at my site looks like:

<div class="commentlist">
[stuff]
<a class="some Classes" href="adress">%Y/%m/%d kl %H:%M</a>
[stuff]
</div>